# if I have legacy code in MFC, how can I migrate it to .NET so I can utilize other people's .net classes and .net APIs?

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I have legacy code in Visual C++ 6.0 and have been limited in expanding it since it is not compatible with .NET APIs.  I am not sure how to go about migrating it.  thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736) talks about calling .net managed code from C++

If you want to add WPF support to your MFC app it is [is covered here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744829.aspx)

You can also recompile your app with [Common Language Runtime support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx) and call .net API's through **[C++/CLI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/05/20/599434.aspx)**